# Error while using cvBlobsLib library in Android native code

Tags: android, opencv, makefile, android-ndk

I need to use the cvBlobsLib library ([cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib/#Build_intructions)) in Android native code. The problem is when I run the Android.mk file, I am getting an error:

> fatal error: OpenCV/opencv/cxcore.h: No such file or directory

This is my make file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
include ../OpenCV-4.2/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MINE_SRC_FILES := \
    micr/cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3/blob.cpp \
    micr/cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3/BlobContour.cpp \
    micr/cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3/BlobOperators.cpp \
    micr/cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3/BlobProperties.cpp \
    micr/cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3/BlobResult.cpp \
    micr/cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3/ComponentLabeling.cpp \

#####
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MINE_SRC_FILES)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=  \
    $(LOCAL_PATH) \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/native/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/native/cvblobslib_opencv_v8_3 \

LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := native
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := native

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

While in OpenCV.mk there is an include for the folder with that header:

> OPENCV_LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:="$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(OPENCV_THIS_DIR)/include/opencv" "$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(OPENCV_THIS_DIR)/include"

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix the header to include  instead of import "opencv/cxcore.h"
:)